# JS: How to make second function await for first function result?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've 2 functions, I need function B to run after function A is complete.

I've read some documentation and according to them I need to use `async` and `await`.

**function A**:

My function A involves some AJAX calling. I've set up a promise.

```
function get_initial_prices() {

         return new Promise(resolve => {

         var size_selected = $('input[name=size]:checked').val();
                        var c_slug = $('.c_slug').text();
                        var product_slug = $('.product_slug').text();

            req = $.ajax({
                     url: "/prices/",
                      data: { // Pass parameters in separate object
                       size_selected: size_selected,
                        c_slug: c_slug,
                        product_slug: product_slug
                      },
                  });


             req.done(function (response) {
                  $('#prices').empty();
                  var prices = response.prices;
                  $('.price').text(function (index) {
                      return "S/ " + prices[index];
                  });
                 });
               });
            }
```

**function B:** for now this function will only collect the text in all span elements with `.price` class and alert them. These texts where rendered by `function A`.

```
function calculate_savings() {

       await get_initial_prices();

       var prices = $(".price")
                    .map(function () {
                    return $(this).text().replace('S/ ', '');
                    }).get().join();

       alert("savings: " + prices);
}
```

I call both of them when document is ready, but `get_initial_prices` should run first:

```
$("document").ready(function () {

    get_initial_prices();
    calculate_savings();

   });
```

Comment: Where is `get_initial_prices` calling `resolve()` ?

Comment: Also if `calculate_savings` is calling `get_initial_prices`, why are you calling `get_initial_prices` in the document ready?  That's going to do the ajax call for initial prices twice

Comment: @Taplar `get_initial_prices` gets some prices from backend and renders them in html span tags. When this is done, I need to collect this prices and make some calculations with `calculate_savings` (this other function will render it's result to another tags).

Comment: Right, so if you are calling it in the calculate, an `await`ing on it to finish, why do you also need to call it in the document ready?

Comment: @Taplar `get_initial_prices` gets some prices from backend and renders them in html span tags. When this is done, I need to collect this prices and make some calculations with `calculate_savings` (this other function will render it's result to another tags).

Comment: You answered the exact same thing, which ignores an issue i'm pointing out.  You're doing the same work twice, for the initial_prices.  I see nothing with the logic that would make the first call to initial_prices be different from the second time.  So you are unnecessarily calling it twice.

Comment: @Taplar I don't need to call it in the document ready. I'm not sure what I need to do to make this work. According to my understanding I have to do that.

Comment: You just need to remove it from the document ready, fix the issue with not calling `resolve()` in the `Promise` (or do what trincot says and not make a new one)`, and then your calculate method should work as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create a promise with `new Promise`, when `$.ajax` returns one already.

Also, you can only use `await` in an `async` function. And it makes no sense to call `get_initial_prices` both in `calculate_savings` and in the `ready` callback.

For instance:

```
function get_initial_prices() {
    var size_selected = $('input[name=size]:checked').val();
    var c_slug = $('.c_slug').text();
    var product_slug = $('.product_slug').text();

    return $.ajax({
        url: "/prices/",
        data: { // Pass parameters in separate object
            size_selected: size_selected,
            c_slug: c_slug,
            product_slug: product_slug
        },
    }).then(function (response) {
        $('#prices').empty();
        var prices = response.prices;
        $('.price').text(function (index) {
            return "S/ " + prices[index];
        });
    });
}

async function calculate_savings() {
    await get_initial_prices();
    var prices = $(".price").map(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace('S/ ', '');
    }).get().join();
    alert("savings: " + prices);
}

$("document").ready(function () {
    calculate_savings();
});
```

I should add though that it is strange to first use the response to write the prices on the page, to then immediately extract those prices again from the page into an array. Seems like you should just keep track of the response, which already is such an array.

Comment: Ignore Update 1. Your answer works. Didn't notice you also change done method for then in Ajax call. Just for curiosity why? what is the difference?

Comment: `then` is newer, and aligns with the native Promise interface. That is why it works with `await`. `done` (and its friends) should not be used any more in my opinion.

Comment: totally right on you last parragraph. I'll `calculate_savings` inside the then method.

Answer (score -1):

Simplified version of your function (pay attention to "data" and "responseData" variables)

```
function get_initial_prices() {
return new Promise(resolve => {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/prices/"
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert('get_initial_prices fired!');
        resolve(data);
    });
})
}

function calculate_savings(responseData) {
    alert(responseData);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    get_initial_prices().then(calculate_savings);
});
```

Comment: The Promise creation is unnecessary, and actually in this case is an anti-pattern

Comment: I checked correct answer, and i agree with you. But in this very problem, promises are unnecessary at all - he can use simple callbacks. It depends of the complexity of the application. I have 1 more question though: how to get response data in "calculate_savings" not using DOM elements?

Comment: Err, promises are necessary.  $.ajax returns a promise.  Without promises, this whole thing would be procedural and blocking.  Unless I misunderstand your statement.

Comment: As far not using DOM elements to pass around the data, look at the method this answer is giving `done()`.  That's not using DOM elements, right?  `done()` gives the method the response data.  Nothing says you can't do `done(calculate_savings)` and then that same data would be passed into `calculate_savings`

Comment: In my daily work i'm working with small, procedural apps, so not completely understand promises yet

Comment: Ok so to clarify your statement.  Making your own promises are unnecessary, as ajax already inheriently uses promises. @jacqbus